# Live tv channels streaming in android

Tags: android, live-streaming

I want to introduce a feature in which the user can select a tv channel and can see this channel on his mobile device.

Anyone know about this live tv channel streaming. If yes than pl help me.

Comment: Plz share how you solve this?

Comment: I haven't find ay best solution of this till now

Comment: I have some solution regarding this you want to develop this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use following code to play Live Streaming Channel in videoview.

```
String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
    setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

You need to play `rtsp` format for play channels in video. So [Here is list of some Channels with rtsp format](http://www.perfectneed.com/rtsp-links-list-for-mobile-tv-and-pc-tv-streaming/) is used to play live streaming channels.

Also note that Live streaming required fast internet connection, will get blur video if you are on 2g connection.

Comment: waoooooo... Its useful link.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Link is not active anymore.

Comment: this may be old but is there's a way to fetch the stream url somewhere per country ?

Comment: Hi @ralphgabb sorry I don't know about it.

Comment: have you had the chance to display the Live TV in an app ? without using a stream URL ?

Comment: @ralphgabb would you please share some info? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HardikJoshi do you mind for a chat ? Join here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/195039/android-tv-chat?tab=general

Comment: @ralphgabb okay